# Como criar um algorítmo indeterminado usando visualg?

Tags: algoritmo, portugol, visualg

Preciso criar um algorítimo que me retorne valores diferentes cada vez que é executado, mesmo recebendo os mesmos valores de entrada.

Visa resolver uma questão onde preciso analisar a geração de determinado ser vivo que tem mais chances de não ter filhos do que de ter, e criar um algorítimo que calcule suas gerações enquanto tiver filhos, e diga que entrou em extinção quando não houver mais filhos.

Comment: O que seria indeterminado?

Comment: Um algorítmo que me retorne valores diferentes cada vez que é executado, mesmo recebendo os mesmos valores de entrada.

Comment: Já melhorou um pouco, edite a pergunta e adicione essa descrição na pergunta :)

Comment: perdão, sou novo no fórum e mais novo ainda no curso de Sistemas da Computação, por isso estou um pouco perdido.
Eu preciso resolver uma questão que pergunta quantas gerações um ser vivo irá durar, sendo que ele tem maior probabilidade de não ter filhos, do que de ter... aí preciso criar um algorítmo que vá dizendo quantos filhos ele teve geração após geração, até entrar em extinção.

Comment: Quando tiver um tempo veja a [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) ela explica rapidamente como o site funciona, ele é uma Q&A e não um fórum, imagino q essa a primeira de varias perguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode dizer que ao colocar um valor na variável x, ele vai fazer um sorteio, ai toda vez que você digitar o mesmo valor vai dar um valor diferente.

Exemplo:

```
    var:
    x:inteiro; //Valor a ser inserido
    resultado:inteiro
    null:caracter
inicio
aleatorio on
    resultado
    aleatorio off
escreval("Digite o valor de x")
leia(x)
se x>=1 entao
escreval("resultado é= ")
leia(resultado)
senao
escreval("Campo vazio")
leia(null)

fimse
fimalgoritmo
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUxdrZLj9uk

Espero ter ajudado, mesmo estando enferrujada no portugol